# Using Dragonfly (Opera) as HTML/CSS editor

Tags: javascript, css, html, opera-dragonfly

I like the integration of the Dragonfly IDE in the Opera Browser. Especially, the link between the visual and the code perspective allow easy editing of the corresponding HTML code. However, I have not found a way to save my changes to the local file.

- I have a simple static website that is stored on my local harddisk.
- I open the file in Opera Developer (Version 28.0)
- I use the 'inspect element ctrl+shift+i' menu option to open dragonfly
- I make the changes and check them in the browser
- I save the html file from dragonfly

Observation: changes are not saved.

[image]

Is there way to save the interactive changes permanently?

Comment: same problem here, I think this post needs more attention

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible, It's just a developer tool.
You can change it on Dragonfly but it won't modify the file.
2 solutions :

1. you change manually the HTML file with an editor like Notepad after each change on dragonfly
2. You use some software like Dreamweaver that allow you to see what you're editing in real time and save these changes.